# Is there any way to reset all static properties of a particular class?

Tags: php, static, phpunit

Static properties make testing hard as you probably know. Is there no way to reset all static properties of a particular class back to their initial state? Ideally this would not require custom code for each class, but could be used in a general way by inheritance, or from outside of the class completely.

Please do not reply with something like, "don't use static properties". Thanks.

Comment: are you using a testing framework such as PHPUnit?  This would be taken care of in the setup/teardown routines for a test module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP does not preserve that information.

I was toying around with [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/ReflectionClass) and `::getDefaultProperties` and `::getStaticProperties`, but they only return the current state.

You will have to create an array with the default values, then manually foreach over them and reset your class attributes.

Comment: Note: `getDefaultProperties` MUST be called before the static properties are modified in order to get the default values.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using PHPUnit:

See the PHPUnit Manual [section about global state](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.global-state). Static members are covered by this if you have PHP 5.3 or higher. Static members are not part of serialization (in case you wonder).

See as well [`@backupGlobals`](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.backupGlobals) and [`@backupStaticAttributes`](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.backupStaticAttributes)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any way to include or require classes or functions many times without getting an error.

Anyway, if you need to replace functions inside an structure you should make an **array/ArrayObject** of **lamdas/inline functions** (like javascript objects)

When you re import the array it will back to the original state.

```
$Animal = array(
    'eat' => function($food) {/*...*/},
    'run' => function($to_place) {/*...*/}
);
$Animal['eat'] = function($food) {/* new way to eat */}
```

I also managed to reset the state of static attributes by using **Reflections**. For this approach you need to use a convention attribute naming for default value of each type.

```
class MyStaticHolder {
    public static $x_array = array();
    public static $x_num = 0;
    public static $x_str = '';
}

//change values
MyStaticHolder::$x_array = array(1,2,4);
MyStaticHolder::$x_num = -1.4;
MyStaticHolder::$x_str = 'sample-text';

function reset_static($class_name) {
    $z = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
    $properties = $z->getDefaultProperties();
    print_r($properties);
    foreach ($properties as $property_name => $value) {
        $sufix = end(explode('_',$property_name));
        switch ($sufix) {
            case 'array':
                $class_name::$$property_name = array();
                break;
            case 'num':
                $class_name::$$property_name = 0;
                break;
            case 'str':
                $class_name::$$property_name = '';
                break;
            default:
                $class_name::$$property_name = null;
                break;
        }
    }
}

reset_static('MyStaticHolder');
```